# SQL Recursive Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have two tables I am joining with the following structure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContentDivider](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ContentDivider] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CustomPage]    Script Date: 23-03-2020 17:46:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomPage](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ContentDividerId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomPage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

A ContentDivider can have `n` ContentDividers as Children and can have `m` CustomPages as children as well.
I want a View that counts the Display the current CustomDivider and the COunt for  all the CustomPages as Children of the current ContentDivider.

My Test data:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name]) VALUES (1, NULL, N'TopLevel1')
INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name]) VALUES (2, NULL, N'TopLevel2')
INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name]) VALUES (3, NULL, N'TopLevel3')
INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name]) VALUES (4, 1, N'SecondLevel1')
INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name]) VALUES (5, 1, N'SecondLevel2')
INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name]) VALUES (6, 1, N'SecondLevel3')
INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name]) VALUES (7, 4, N'ThirdLevel1')
INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name]) VALUES (8, 4, N'ThirdLevel2')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ContentDivider] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ([Id], [ContentDividerId], [Name]) VALUES (1, 1, N'Level1_1')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ([Id], [ContentDividerId], [Name]) VALUES (2, 1, N'Level1_2')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ([Id], [ContentDividerId], [Name]) VALUES (3, 2, N'Level1_3')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ([Id], [ContentDividerId], [Name]) VALUES (4, 2, N'Level1_4')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ([Id], [ContentDividerId], [Name]) VALUES (5, 4, N'Level1_5')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ([Id], [ContentDividerId], [Name]) VALUES (6, 5, N'Level1_6')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ([Id], [ContentDividerId], [Name]) VALUES (7, 7, N'Level1_7')
INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] ([Id], [ContentDividerId], [Name]) VALUES (8, 8, N'Level1_8')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[CustomPage] OFF
GO
```

And the View I want to extend:

```
SELECT        dbo.ContentDivider.ParentId, dbo.ContentDivider.Name, dbo.ContentDivider.Id, COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CustomPage.Id) AS CustomPageCount
FROM            dbo.ContentDivider LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.CustomPage ON dbo.ContentDivider.Id = dbo.CustomPage.ContentDividerId
GROUP BY dbo.ContentDivider.ParentId, dbo.ContentDivider.Name, dbo.ContentDivider.Id
```

As for now the view counts the custompages directly underneath the contentdivider. I would like all the CustomPages as children counted.
Any suggestions?

The respected result would be:

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYBYP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sounds like a perfect situation for recursive cte ;)
So, if I understood correctly, your expected result would be Toplevel1 with 6 pages and Toplevel 2 with 2 pages since all the other levels are somewhere beneath these two mentioned levels?

The cte might look something like this (maybe you habe to include the max recursion option):

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT 1 lvl, ID AS ParentID, ID, Name
  FROM dbo.ContentDivider cd
  WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT c.lvl+1 AS lvl, c.ParentID, cd.ID, cd.Name
  FROM dbo.ContentDivider cd
  INNER JOIN cte c ON cd.ParentID = c.ID
)
SELECT c.ParentID, cd.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT cp.Id) AS CustomPageCount
  FROM cte c
  JOIN dbo.ContentDivider cd ON cd.ID = c.ParentID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomPage cp ON cp.ContentDividerId = c.id
  GROUP BY c.ParentId, cd.Name
```

This leads to all pages being assigned to its top level.

See fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f1a44/28/1

Edit: Since you need the details down to DividerID, I extended my example in the fiddle. First of all, I fetch the PageCount per ID in one cte and additionally the PageCount aggregated on level (ParentID and all its IDs) - this done you don't need the count and grouping in the following ctes.
In my query I then check, if my current rows ID is a top-level of any kind and assign the corresponding PageCount to this row.

```
WITH cteCnt AS(
  SELECT cd.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT cp.Id) AS CustomPageCount
    FROM dbo.ContentDivider cd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomPage cp ON cp.ContentDividerId = cd.id
    GROUP BY cd.ID
),
cteTop AS(
  SELECT cd.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT cp.Id) AS CustomPageCount
    FROM dbo.ContentDivider cd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomPage cp ON cp.ContentDividerId = cd.id
    GROUP BY cd.ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cd.ParentID, COUNT(DISTINCT cp.Id) AS CustomPageCount
    FROM dbo.ContentDivider cd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomPage cp ON cp.ContentDividerId = cd.id
    WHERE cd.ParentID IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY cd.ParentID
),
cteTopSum AS(
SELECT ID, SUM(CustomPageCount) AS CustomPageCount
  FROM ctetop
  GROUP BY ID
),  
cte AS(
SELECT 1 lvl, cd.ID AS ParentID, cd.ID AS ParentIDx, cd.ID, cd.Name, cnt.CustomPageCount
  FROM dbo.ContentDivider cd
  INNER JOIN cteCnt cnt ON cnt.ID = cd.ID
  WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT c.lvl+1 AS lvl, c.ParentID, cd.ParentID AS ParentIDx, cd.ID, cd.Name, cnt.CustomPageCount
  FROM dbo.ContentDivider cd
  INNER JOIN cteCnt cnt ON cnt.ID = cd.ID
  INNER JOIN cte c ON cd.ParentID = c.ID
),
cteOut AS(
SELECT *
  ,SUM(CustomPageCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID) x
  ,SUM(CustomPageCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentIDx) y
  FROM cte c
)
SELECT CASE WHEN co.ParentIDx = co.ID THEN NULL ELSE co.ParentIDx END AS ParentID, co.ID, co.Name, CASE WHEN co.ID = co.ParentID THEN co.X ELSE ts.CustomPageCount END CustomPageCount
  FROM cteOut co
  LEFT JOIN cteTopSum ts ON ts.ID = co.ID
  ORDER BY 1, 2
```

See new fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f1a44/185/1

I'm mot sure, if there is a prettier / nicer way to solve this, but seemingly this seems to solve the problem.
However, I did NOT check if it works if any number of sublevels or whatsoever - if you find any issues, feel free to comment.

Comment: thats a good step on the way, though I need all the Contentdividers in the result. I have just uploaded an image above with the respected result.

Comment: @SirLanceLang I edited my post and added a new fiddle example.

Comment: sorry about that. I did not mark it correctly as answered.